# Post to a Google Plus page

Tags: ruby, google-plus

How do I post to a Google+ page using Ruby?

By "page" I mean one of the brand pages (e.g., https://plus.google.com/105033245922189902491/posts)

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the Google Plus API seems to be read only

From https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**
Google just released a new History API for Google+ that lets you write programmatically to the Google Plus Stream

https://developers.google.com/+/history/learn-more

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this link](https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/17t83h6a4w0ar/?content=weihmao&v=compose). Or a plugin form [here](http://www.stateofsearch.com/share-on-google-plus-any-website/).They work the same way actually.

It does not utilize the API power, but it CAN work.

I am working on improving this functionality and make it simpler for user to post activities.

Answer (score 0):

There has been developments and these guys figured out a way around the read only part. There is a software called Google Plus SecondLife and it allows the user to make posts to Google+ and even has a feature to spoof their location. There is a video just put up about it on youtube over here.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=vBVU_75w6b4